# DbProviderFactory with Npgsql?

Tags: .net, postgresql, mono, dbproviderfactories

I have a project which I'm trying to port from SQL Server to PostgreSQL. I've got almost everything done I believe except for I can not get `DbProviderFactory` to work with Npgsql.

```
Factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Npgsql");
```

yields

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException:
>   Failed to find or load the registered
>   .Net Framework Data Provider.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you read section 3.4 "Using Npgsql with ProviderFactory" from [the fine manual](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html)?

Comment: Actually I read it and adding it to machine.config didn't work. I checked and the version that comes with Mono for Arch Linux(2.0.0.0) didn't support it. I upgraded to the latest version and now everything is good

Comment: This link is broken. Refer to ANeves's answer and step 4 of this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/783552/Using-PostgreSQL-with-Entity-Framework-in-ASP-NET

Comment: [Actual link](https://github.com/danzel/Npgsql/blob/master/docs/UserManual.html) refers to github ;)

Answer (score 15):

Try defining a factory in your app.config:

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql"
         description="Data Provider for PostgreSQL"
         type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Via http://fxjr.blogspot.pt/2013/06/npgsql-code-first-entity-framework-431.html

Comment: Up to date link for the official documentation: https://www.npgsql.org/doc/installation.html

Answer (score 1):

The **type** attribute value is important in the **DbProviderFactories** entry.

For me, the **version number** was incorrect.
Correct version was :

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" 
         invariant="Npgsql" 
         support="FF" 
         description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql Server" 
         type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=2.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

You can retrieve the value on your project with :

```
typeof(Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName
```

Answer (score 1):

These were the steps that resolved it for me:

(1) add DbFactory provider to machine.config file located in the .NET Microsoft Frameworking folder

(2) register npgsql.dll and mono.security.dll in GAC using gacutil

---

Step by step details for:

(1) add DbFactory provider to machine.config

a. go to your relevant NET framework config directory (e.g. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config)

b. edit the machine.config file and add the below line to DbProviderFactories

```
<DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" 
         invariant="Npgsql" 
         support="FF" 
         description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql Server" 
         type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql"/>
  </DbProviderFactories>
```

(2) register npgsql.dll and mono.security.dll in GAC

a. check if npgsql and mono.security is in GAC folder
(my GAC folder was located at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL)

If not, then use gacutil to install npgsql to GAC in command prompt using gacutil /i npgsql.dll

Answer (score 0):

register ngsql and mono.security dll in GAC and add dbfactory provider in machine.config for both[32 & 64 bit version ]

Comment: This answer could be more useful with some code examples to illustrate how to register assemblies in the GAC and how to modify machine.config, along with how to locate them.